# Execute multiple CMD commands in same process (window) without showing separate windows

Tags: c#, command-line, console-application, ctags

I am using a code parser [CTAG](http://ctags.sourceforge.net/) which parses a file at a time and report the results in a text file. I have a list of files that I parse and process their output with the following code.

```
        string folder = "C:\\Temp\\";
        Process p = new Process();
        p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        p.StartInfo.FileName = folder + "command.bat";
        foreach (string file in files)
        {
            string command = @"ctags -R --c++-kinds=+p --fields=+iaS --extra=+q " + file;
            File.WriteAllText(folder + "command.bat", "cd " + folder + Environment.NewLine + command);
            p.Start();
            p.WaitForExit();
            string[] str = File.ReadAllLines(folder + "tags");
            ProcessParsedCode(str);
        }
```

The above code keeps opening and closing a new window for parsing each file which looks ugly as I have over 100 files. I want to do this in one command window.

Comment: Have you tried setting `WindowStyle` to `Hidden`? - `p.StartInfo.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;`

Comment: What about hiding the command windows with `p.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;`?

Comment: changing WindowStyle doesn't help, CreateNoWindow does. Thanks @Rawns.

Comment: No problem, I've added it as an answer as it helped. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are running the process for each 'file' in 'files'. Therefore if you have 100 files, it will result in 100 command windows.

If you're not interested in the output contained within those command windows (and as you're outputting the results to a text file, I'll presume not), you can just hide them with all with `p.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;`.